# Ada hello world example

Tags: ada

I have written a simple hello world program in Ada and when I compile it using gnatmake  I get an executable file called "hello". However, when I try to run the program by typing "hello" I get command not found error. I am using Linux VM and gcc compiler. What could be the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a path issue. If you don't have your current directory in the path, try to run it with:

```
./hello
```

If the executable is in a different directory (that still isn't in your path), use the fully qualified executable name,, something like (you'll need to substitute your *actual* path):

```
/full/path/to/hello
```

Comment: it worked! I am new to linux. Did not know Linux doesn't automatically add current directory to path.

Comment: @user732362, it's primarily a security thing so you can't be tricked into running a fake copy of `ls` or something similar, that happens to be in the current directory.